# Create a list from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Consider the following dataframe:

```
test.df <- data.frame(a = c("1991-01-01","1991-01-01","1991-02-01","1991-02-01"), b = rnorm(4), c = rnorm(4))
```

I would like to create a list from `test.df`. Each element of the list would be a subset dataframe of `test.df` corresponding to a specific value of `column a`, i.e. each date. In other words, in this case, `column a` takes unique values `1991-01-01` and `1991-02-01`. Therefore, the resulting list would be comprised of two elements: the subset of `test.df` when `a = 1991-01-01` (excluding column `a`), and the other element of the list would be the subset of `test.df` when `1991-02-01 = 2` (excluding column `a`). Here is the output I am looking for:

```
lst <- list(test.df[1:2,2:3], test.df[3:4,2:3])
```

Note that the subset dataframes may not have the same number of rows.

In my real practical example, column `a` is a date column with many more values.

I would appreciate any attempt of help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: `lst` is the example of output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `split`

```
lst <- split(test.df, test.df$a)
```

If you want to get rid of column `a`, use `split(test.df[-1], test.df$a)` (thanks to @akrun for comment).

Comment: You could use `split(test.df[,-1], test.df$a)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
sapply(union(test.df$a,NULL), function(y,x) x[x$a==y,], x=test.df, simplify=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `dlply` function in the `plyr` package:

```
> library(plyr)

> dlply(test.df, .(a))
$`1991-01-01`
           a          b         c
1 1991-01-01  1.3658775 0.9805356
2 1991-01-01 -0.2292211 2.2812914

$`1991-02-01`
           a          b         c
1 1991-02-01 -0.2678131 0.5323250
2 1991-02-01  0.3736910 0.4988308
```

Or the `data.table` package:

```
> library(data.table)

> setDT(test.df)
> dt <- test.df[, list(list(.SD)), by = a]$V1
> names(dt) <- unique(test.df$a)

> dt
$`1991-01-01`
            b         c
1:  1.3658775 0.9805356
2: -0.2292211 2.2812914

$`1991-02-01`
            b         c
1: -0.2678131 0.5323250
2:  0.3736910 0.4988308
```